# Does auto arima predict function return series

Tags: python, pandas, arima, pmdarima

I have been following this tutorial:
https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/11/basic-understanding-of-time-series-modelling-with-auto-arimax/

I was fitting it on my dataset.
It was working fine but when I ran it again the next day model.predict function started returning series rather than a list. And it is not giving proper results like it did previously.

```
model = pm.auto_arima(df_train["farm rate"], exogenous=df_train[exogenous_features], trace=True, error_action="ignore", suppress_warnings=True)
model.fit(df_train["farm rate"], exogenous=df_train[exogenous_features])

forecast = model.predict(n_periods=len(df_valid), exogenous=df_valid[exogenous_features])
df_valid["Forecast_ARIMAX"] = forecast
```

My df looks like this

```
                date    day doc farm rate   open    close   price   month   year    day_of_week week    doc_mean_3  open_mean_3 close_mean_3    price_mean_3
date                                                            
2015-01-01  2015-01-01  1.0 51.5    165.0   170.0   170.0   2375.0  1.0 2015.0  3.0 1.0 38.574580   155.158973  150.355472  3418.872350
2015-01-02  2015-01-02  2.0 48.5    165.0   170.0   160.0   2375.0  1.0 2015.0  4.0 1.0 38.574580   155.158973  150.355472  3418.872350
2015-01-03  2015-01-03  3.0 44.5    150.0   180.0   167.5   2375.0  1.0 2015.0  5.0 1.0 48.166667   173.333333  165.833333  2375.000000
2015-01-05  2015-01-05  5.0 40.5    150.0   165.0   155.0   2375.0  1.0 2015.0  0.0 2.0 44.500000   171.666667  160.833333  2375.000000
2015-01-06  2015-01-06  6.0 36.5    140.0   155.0   152.5   2375.0  1.0 2015.0  1.0 2.0 40.500000   166.666667  158.333333  2375.000000
2015-01-07  2015-01-07  7.0 35.5    140.0   155.0   150.0   2375.0  1.0 2015.0  2.0 2.0 37.500000   158.333333  152.500000  2375.000000
2015-01-08  2015-01-08  8.0 35.5    140.0   162.5   155.0   2375.0  1.0 2015.0  3.0 2.0 35.833333   157.500000  152.500000  2375.000000
2015-01-09  2015-01-09  9.0 37.5    145.0   165.0   157.5   2375.0  1.0 2015.0  4.0 2.0 36.166667   160.833333
```

I have data from 2015 to 2022.Exogenous features are : ["doc", "open","close","doc_mean_3", "open_mean_3",  "close_mean_3", "price_mean_3"]
They are calculated using this method:

```
def calc_lag_features(df, feature, window):
  
    df[f"{feature}_mean_{window}"] = df[feature].rolling(window=window).mean()
    return df
```

Edit:
These are the results I get. Completely flat graph. Adding or removing exogenous variables isnt making any difference. Previously, it was able to capture the true graph to quite an extent.
[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGgFt.png)

Depending on exogenous variables straight line only goes up and down and is not able to capture the true trend.

Comment: Do you want to change to format, i.e. make a list by using `list()`. Or are the numbers unexpected? If so, please insert your outcome, and the expected outcome.

Comment: @TobiasMolenaar numbers are unexpected. Let me add

Comment: I think you will get more answers here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/